# "RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (...) already deleted" only when running code on .ui file widgets

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm using PySide2 inside Houdini.

I load a .UI file made in QtDesigner which contains a checkbox called `cb_wipe_network` and is accessible after loading the file as `self.ui.cb_wipe_network`

I then generate more checkbox widgets using code (`generate_engine_UI()`) and somehow they don't have any issues.

I have identified that this line of code is directly related to or responsible for the error:
`widget = layout.itemAt(i).widget()` in `retrieve_settings()`

Here's a fragment of my code that I hope is enough:

```py
class MaterialCreator(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MaterialCreator,self).__init__()

        ui_file = hou.expandString('$MYTOOL/main_window.ui')
        self.ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(ui_file, parentWidget=self)
        self.setParent(hou.ui.mainQtWindow(), QtCore.Qt.Window)

        ...
     
        self.generate_engine_UI()

        #prints: Check .ui file widget: <PySide2.QtWidgets.QCheckBox(0x7fb672ddfb20, name="cb_wipe_network") at 0x7fb6e00a5e00>
        print(f"Check .ui file widget: {self.ui.cb_wipe_network}") 

        #prints: Check generated widget: <PySide2.QtWidgets.QCheckBox(0x7fb64ff535c0, name="cb_use_redshift") at 0x7fb6e0065e40>
        print(f"Check generated widget: {self.ui.cb_use_redshift}") 

        self.retrieve_settings()

        #prints: Check generated widget again: <PySide2.QtWidgets.QCheckBox(0x7fb64ff535c0, name="cb_use_redshift") at 0x7fb6e0065e40>
        print(f"Check generated widget again: {self.ui.cb_use_redshift}") 

        ###### RuntimeError: ###########################################################
        ###### Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QCheckBox) already deleted.#######
        print(f"Check .ui file widget again: {self.ui.cb_wipe_network}") 
        ################################################################################

    def generate_engine_UI(self):
        """
        Dynamically creates UI checkboxes from JSON files.
        """
        for engine in lookup:
            # create engine enabling checkbox
            checkbox_name = lookup[engine]["engine_enable_checkbox"]
            checkbox_instance = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
            checkbox_instance.setText(engine)
            checkbox_instance.setObjectName(checkbox_name)
            checkbox_instance.setChecked(True)
            setattr(self.ui, checkbox_name, checkbox_instance)
            self.ui.engines_layout.addWidget( getattr(self.ui, checkbox_name, None) )
            
            # create options checkboxes
            if "options_checkboxes" in lookup[engine]:
                for option in lookup[engine]["options_checkboxes"]:
                    checkbox_name = option["ui_name"]
                    checkbox_instance = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
                    checkbox_instance.setText(option["name"])
                    checkbox_instance.setObjectName(checkbox_name)
                    checkbox_instance.setChecked(True)
                    setattr(self.ui, checkbox_name, checkbox_instance)
                    self.ui.engine_options_layout.addWidget( getattr(self.ui, checkbox_name, None) )

    def retrieve_settings(self):
        layouts = [self.ui.engines_layout, self.ui.engine_options_layout, self.ui.main_options_layout]
        for layout in layouts:
            for i in range(layout.count()):
                ####### THIS LINE BREAKS IT: ########
                widget = layout.itemAt(i).widget()  
                #####################################
                widget_name = widget.objectName()
                if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QCheckBox):
                    if self.settings.contains(widget_name):
                        widget.setChecked(self.settings.value(widget_name))
```

Why is it happening? Why doesn't the error occur with code-generated widgets?

Comment: What makes you think that that line "breaks it"? Note that there's no guarantee that a layout item actually has a widget, so you should also ensure that `widget is not None`. In any case, I'd start by simplifying things in order to ease out debugging by removing distracting and unnecessary boilerplate code: for instance, by directly using `checkbox_instance` (instead of a pointless `getattr`) for `addWidget()`, or iterating through keys *and* values of the dictionary instead of continuously retrieving the values.

Comment: @musicamante Because removing this line and the rest of code below it stops the error from occurring. I just tried it with `layout_item = layout.itemAt(i)` and that's the part that breaks it, not `.widget()` it seems. I appreciate the tips.

Comment: Do you mean that if you just put `layout.itemAt(i)` in the inner for loop (and *nothing else* in the loop), you still get that error, while if you just put a simple `pass`, everything is fine? Does the same happens even if you don't call `generate_engine_UI()`? Note that it seems like `hou.ui.mainQtWindow` is deprecated, and `hou.qt.mainWindow` should be used instead. I don't know if it's just a matter of naming, but trying it won't hurt (I doubt it would change, but I don't use Houdini, so, who knows?).

Comment: @musicamante Exactly. Just `layout.itemAt(i)` in the loop and nothing else. And with `pass` it works. It's almost as if it corrupts the widget somehow. It does also happen when I don't `generate_engine_UI`. Unfortunately `hou.qt.mainWindow`, while a good call, doesn't save us either. Meanwhile, I also tried differently nested layouts in QtDesigner. I'm now fully convinced it's a bug of PySide2. it wouldn't be the first time. It's a bit funny, I spent like half a day on this now and it's just one checkbox I could have hardcoded, but curiosity has gotten the best of me. Thanks! :)

Comment: I sincerely doubt that the culprit is exactly `itemAt()`, but it could be a symptom of another issue that simply is delayed by queued events. It could even be a bug, so it's important to understand it. I also don't know if Houdini still uses its own internal build of PySide, and that could be relevant too. I notice that you added an ellipses between calling `generate_engine_UI()`. What do you do there? And how are the three layouts created? Also, the UI you created in Designer is a widget or a main window?

Comment: @AlexM What is the output of `print('PS:', QtCore.__version__, 'QT:', QtCore.qVersion())` when run from inside Houdini? This looks like a PySide bug, but that's hard to confirm without knowing the specific versions.

Comment: @musicamante I just created a dummy bare-bones setup with a .ui file that contains just 1 layout and 1 checkbox inside of it. Then I tested it with both Houdini and my system terminal (2 almost indentical scripts). Both worked/survived the `itemAt()` treatment. Then I loaded in my original .UI file and Houdini broke, but the system one worked(!). I then laid out the dummy script .ui (right click background -> Lay Out in Designer) and that finally made it break in Houdini. It seems hopeless and like a bug. Given the above, let me know if you still want me to answer your questions.

Comment: @ekhumoro Houdini PySide2: PS: 5.15.2 QT: 5.15.2, my system ~PySide2:~ PS: 5.15.8 QT: 5.15.8. It works on my system, breaks on Houdini. Edit: Actually no, scratch that, I don't know what this command is exactly pulling from my system.

Comment: @AlexM Please edit your question and add the dummy script and ui file that reproduces the problem. Make sure that this is a proper [mre], so that others can also try to reproduce it.

Comment: @AlexM What do you mean by "I laid out the dummy script .ui"? According to your initial phrase, the "dummy ui" already contains a layout; or you just dragged a layout from the widget box into the ui? That is an important difference, and if you did that we need to know it, and you should include that aspect as a separate test case.